# No of ways to cut a 5 dimensional cake?

Tags: combinatorics

Recently I got sucked in a question. It asks suppose I am given a cake of size $2 × 2 × 2 × 2 × n\cdot (5-D)$
I want to cut it into 8n pieces of small chocolate of size $1 × 1 × 1 × 1 × 2$ each. Here, the direction doesn't matter, $1 × 1 × 1 × 2 × 1$ and $2 × 1 × 1 × 1 × 1$ are acceptable.
In how many ways I can cut the cake for a given $n?$

Hint is given as for $n = 1$,the no of ways will be $272.$

Comment: May I have of piece of it ? **Happy New Year !!**

Comment: Ya sure..:),Happy new year to u too..:)

Comment: Have you tried solving the analogous problem in 1, 2, and 3 dimensions, to see whether any patterns come up that might extend to 5 dimensions?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't think result from $1,2, 3$D help. They can be solved by figuring out the list of "irreducible" sub-blocks and building OGFs from them.
$$
\begin{align}
\text{OGF}_{1D} &= \frac{1}{1-2z}\\
\text{OGF}_{2D} &= \frac{1}{1-(z+z^2)}\\
\text{OGF}_{3D} &= \frac{1}{1 - \left(2z + 4\frac{z^2}{1-z} + z^2\right)} = \frac{1-z}{1-3z-3z^2+z^3}
\end{align}
$$
There doesn't seem to be any recognizable patterns in the coefficients. Start from $4$D, the "irreducible" sub-blocks already becomes too hard to figure out by hand.

Comment: @achille, Thanks. Is your 1D answer right? That's cutting a length $n$ line into $n/2$ blocks of length 2, which I think can only be done in one way for $n$ even, not at all for $n$ odd, so I get $1/(1-z^2)$ as the generating function.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, oops, should be $1/(1-z^2)$ as you say. (there are only one "irreducible" sublock of length $2$).

Comment: For the $4$D case, I get
$$1,9,272,6345,155969,3794880,92524801,2254970505,\ldots$$
An OEIS search returns [OEIS A028456](http://oeis.org/A028456).
According to OEIS, the OGF is
$$\text{OGF}_{4D} = 
\frac{(1+x)(1-16x+45x^2-16x^3+x^4)}{(1-x)(1-23x-50x^2+405x^3-50x^4-23x^5+x^6)}$$
The references on above OEIS entry might be useful for this problem.

Comment: I go through the references in above comment. [OEIS A028467](http://oeis.org/A028467) is probably what you want for the $5$D case. The numbers are computed by Per Hakan Lundow and his paper [Enumeration of matchings in polygraphs](http://www.theophys.kth.se/~phl/Text/1factors2.pdf) cover the underlying methodology. It is a transfer matrix based method and the paper tell us how to compress the matrix to make computation practical. I don't understand any of the stuff in the paper, good luck ;-p

Comment: A very good question, but it is from a [running competition](https://www.codechef.com/JAN16/problems/DMCS)

Comment: @MohitJain FYI, a proper way to deal with running contest is flag it for mod attention, the mod should lock this question until end of contest. I have flagged for you this time.

Comment: Thanks @achillehui. I flagged four question from a running contest on stackexchange websites in past. All flags were decline and people kept answering on the question. Response I got from moderators were: "It's not up to us to enforce codes of conduct for other sites or competitions." and "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention", "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" (twice) and "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"

Comment: @MohitJain It is strange, I though the mods have agreed upon an "ongoing contest policy" sometimes ago (a year?). When we flag, we do need to supply enough information/evidence what contest it is and when do it end. It probably doesn't matter for this particular question b/c this problem is hard enough and there is no easy way to get the answer.